# How to display more posts by changing offset value of the sql request?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I started learning PHP and MySQL not so long ago, right now I'm making a blog and I was wondering how to display more posts on click of the button.

I have a question: If I change `$offset_val` is it going to update posts already on the page? And if not how can I update them dynamicaly?

Also I know that I can't just call a function `onlick="funciton()"` in php, I've tried to call a php function through js function, but it didn't work too.
Help me please

**PHP**

```
include 'db.php';

$offset_val = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET " . $offset_val .";";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$data_array = array();


if ($result_check > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data_array[] = $row; //Put all row values inside array
    };
};

function nextOffset() {
    $offset_val = $offset_val + 3;
    print_r($sql);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide-controlls-right" onclick="nextOffset()">
   <img>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with any of the hundreds of thousands of examples of exactly this kind of thing?